# If statements with UISwitch state in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how I can I write an if statement for the state of a switch. I've tried with this:

```
if switch1 == true{
   label.text = "Light gray"
   scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}
```

Before that I created this outlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var switch1: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

But this isn't working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.on` property.  You don't need to compare against `true` as well this way:

```
if switch1.on {
   label.text = "Light gray"
   scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 Solution**:

The `.on` property has been renamed to `.isOn`, so your code should look somewhat like this:

```
if switch1.isOn {
    label.text = "Light gray"
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}
```